# How can i add a black boder to a formattable object in R?

Tags: r, formattable

I am trying to add a black border to a formattable object.

Here is my example table:

```
df <- data.frame(A = "SSF", B = 100, C = 75, Diff = 100 - 75)

formattable(df, align = c("l", "c", "c",  "r"))
```

Actual output:

[image: Actual output:]

Desired output:
[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the style in the `table.attr` argument inside the `formattable` function.

```
formattable(df, align = c("l", "c", "c", "r"),
                        table.attr = 'style="border: 7px solid black;";\"')
```

[image]